# make two commands into one command

Tags: python

lpthw exercise 17 lesson code:

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, from_file, to_file = argv

print "Copying from %s to %s" % (from_file, to_file)

# we could do these two on one line, how?
in_file = open(from_file)
indata = in_file.read()

print "The input file is %d bytes long" % len(indata)

print "Does the output file exist? %r" % exists(to_file)
print "Ready, hit RETURN to continue, CTRL-C to abort."
raw_input()

out_file = open(to_file, 'w')
out_file.write(indata)

print "Alright, all done."
```

In study drill one, it asks you to take the two line command

```
in_file = open(from_file)
indata = in_file.read()
```

and make it a one line command.

I did this as

```
indata = open(from_file).read()
```

which worked fine.

But then I tried to put the second set of commands together the same way

```
out_file = open(to_file, 'w')
out_file.write(indata)
```

into

```
out_file = open(to_file, 'w').write(indata)
```

and it did not work the way I thought it would. Many people have already posted the correct way to make these commands one line, but I want to know why my first approach does not work. Can anyone here give me a brief explanation?

Comment: "it did not work the way I thought it would"... and what did you expect?

Comment: You should find the a file with `indata` written to it... but `.write(indata)` returns the number of bytes written so `out_file` is likely to contain a number probably the same as `len(indata)`

Comment: `write` returns the number of bytes written. Your code worked.

Comment: Why are you learning Python 2 rather than Python 3? Python 2 reaches its End Of Life in 2020. So unless you _need_ Python 2 to work on a legacy code base you should be using Python 3. And even then, it's probably easier to learn Python 3 first and then learn the differences from Python 2, rather than the other way around.

Comment: FWIW, there's little benefit in combining those pairs of statements into single statements. That lesson code fails to close the files it opens. True, they'll get closed automatically when `in_file` and `out_file` go out of scope (IOW, at the end of the script), but relying on that is poor practice. It's _much_ better to open files using a `with` block, eg `with open(from_file) as in_file:`, that ensures that the files are closed automatically when you leave the `with` block, either through normal execution or a file error.

Comment: Issues like those mentioned in my previous comments are why the SO Python Community do _not_ recommend LPTHW, as discussed [here](http://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints).